# Ruby 1.8 Iconv UTF-16 to UTF-8 fails with "\000" (Iconv::InvalidCharacter)

Tags: ruby, utf-8, character-encoding, utf-16, iconv

I am having trouble handling text files of tabulated data generated on a windows machine.
I'm working in Ruby 1.8. The following gives an error ("\000" (Iconv::InvalidCharacter)) when processing the SECOND line from the file. The first line is converted properly.

```
require 'iconv'
conv = Iconv.new("UTF-8//IGNORE","UTF-16")
infile = File.open(tabfile, "r")
while (line = infile.gets)
  line = conv.iconv(line.strip)  # FAILS HERE
  puts line
  # DO MORE STUFF HERE
end
```

The strange thing is that it reads and converts the first line in the file with no problem.
I have the //IGNORE flag in the Iconv constructor -- I thought this was supposed to suppress this kind of error.

I've been going in circles for a while. Any advice would be highly appreciated.

Thanks!

EDIT:
hobbs solution fixes this. Thank you. 
Simply change the code to:

```
require 'iconv'
conv = Iconv.new("UTF-8//IGNORE","UTF-16")
infile = File.open(tabfile, "r")
while (line = infile.gets("\x0a\x00"))
  line = conv.iconv(line.strip)  # NO LONGER FAILS HERE
  # DOES MORE STUFF HERE
end
```

Now I'll just need to find a way to automatically determine which gets separator to use.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The error message is pretty vague, but I think it's unhappy about the fact that it's found an *odd* number of bytes on a line, since every character in UTF-16 is two (or occasionally four) bytes. And I think the reason for *that* is your use of `gets`-- the lines in your file are separated by a UTF-16le newline, which is `0x0a 0x00`, but `gets` is splitting on (and `strip` is removing) `0x0a` only.

To illustrate: suppose the file contains

```
ab
cd
```

encoded in UTF-16le. That's

```
0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00 0x0a 0x00 0x63 0x00 0x64 0x00 0x0a 0x00
    a         b         \n        c         d         \n
```

`gets` reads up to the first `0x0a`, which `strip` removes, so the first line read is `0x61 0x00 0x62 0x00`, which iconv happily accepts and encodes to UTF-8 as `0x61 0x62` — "ab". `gets` then reads up to the next `0x0a`, which `strip` again removes, so the second time `line` gets `0x00 0x63 0x00 0x64 0x00` and now everything is screwed up — we're out of sync by one byte and there's an odd number of bytes to convert, and `iconv` blows up because that's incompatible with what you asked it to do.

Absent an actual working file encoding/decoding layer, I think what you want is to change the `gets` separator from `"\n"` (`"\x0a"`) to `"\x0a\x00"`, abandon all use of `strip` since it's not encoding-clean, and use `print` instead of `puts` so that you don't add extra line-ends (since you'll be converting the ones you've already got).

If you're working with windows files, a windows CRLF in UTF-16le is `"\x0d\x00\x0a\x00"`.

Answer (score 0):

Answer above is good. You could also convert the entire file to UTF-8 before processing it line-by-line, but that might have worse streaming behaviour on large files.